# How to download files when date is given

Tags: php

I know the basic functionality of PHP file upload and download. I need some idea about how to upload files to a specific date and download when that date is selected.

I need to upload daily reports to server. When user wants to see the report, he needs to select the date. So the reports uploaded that date will be listed and user can download the report. Can anyone help me how to do that using php ?

Comment: you need to store file reference - path to file in db table as well as date of uploading. When you process file uploading insert row to database and current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading the record you should add the date field in the database and insert the date by using the date function in php [date('d-m-y')].

So when downloading the record, you can fetch the record based on selecting the files by date:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `date`= input from user;
```

This will get the records for a particular date.